# Different behaviour of break vs. return in infinite loop when implementing io.Reader

Tags: go, interface, infinite-loop, break

I'm going through the official tour. Today, I met something weird while doing the [rot13reader exercise](https://tour.golang.org/methods/23).

The problem is when I use `break` instead of `return ttl, io.EOF`, the program goes into an infinite loop. However, as far as I know, in this program, there should be no difference with either `break` or `return ttl, io.EOF` because if it's `break`, the next line will be `return ttl, err` at the end of the `Read()` method, which is the same as `return ttl, io.EOF`.

I'm wondering why. Anything to do with the underlying mechanism of how Go handles the io.Reader interface and its implementations?

Here is the code.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
)

type rot13Reader struct {
    r io.Reader
}

func (rr *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    rb := make([]byte, 8)
    var ttl int
    for {
        n, err := rr.r.Read(rb)
        if err == io.EOF {
            return ttl, io.EOF
            // break <----------------------------here's the problem
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            for i, c := range rb[:n] {
                b[i+ttl] = decodeRot13(c)
            }
            ttl += n
        }
    }
    return ttl, err
}

func decodeRot13(c byte) byte {
    if c >= 97 && c <= 122 { // a-z: 97 122
        c += 13
        if c > 122 {
            c -= 26
        }
    } else if c >= 65 && c <= 90 { // A-Z: 65 90
        c += 13
        if c > 90 {
            c -= 26
        }
    }
    return c
}

func main() {
    s := strings.NewReader("Lbh penpxrq gur pbqr!")
    r := rot13Reader{s}
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, &r)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The observed behavior is because of variable shadowing:

```golang
func (rr *rot13Reader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) { // <-- this 'err'
    rb := make([]byte, 8)
    var ttl int
    for {
        n, err := rr.r.Read(rb) // <-- and this 'err' are different
        if err == io.EOF {
            return ttl, io.EOF
            // break <----------------------------here's the problem
        } else if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        } else {
            for i, c := range rb[:n] {
                b[i+ttl] = decodeRot13(c)
            }
            ttl += n
        }
    }
    return ttl, err
}
```

On this line:

```golang
        n, err := rr.r.Read(rb) // <-- and this 'err' are different
```

because of the `:=` assignment, a new instance of `err` is created, which shadows the one defined at the higher scope. This means that when you exit the for loop, this version of `err` is not available, and the higher-scoped version, which is set to `nil`, is used.

This is why `return ttl, err` is the same as `return ttl, nil`, and not at all the same as `return ttl, io.EOF`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You taught me something today! Looking around on the web, there are other people who had the same experience with me, [here](https://rpeshkov.net/blog/golang-variable-shadowing/), [here](http://devs.cloudimmunity.com/gotchas-and-common-mistakes-in-go-golang/index.html#vars_shadow).

Comment: Yes, this is a very common problem. I've closed about half a dozen duplicates with a similar root cause in the last 2 days (but yours was distinct enough to be worth a separate answer, IMO)